# Assess position of member at compile time

Tags: c++, pointers, compile-time

Consider the following example:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    mystruct x;

    std :: cout << reinterpret_cast <size_t> (&(x.b)) - reinterpret_cast <size_t> (&x) << std :: endl;
}
```

What the above does is to use `reinterpret_cast`s to determine the position of member `b` in memory within the struct `mystruct`. On my system (and, I guess, on any reasonable system) the above yields `4`.

Now, what I would need is to do exactly the same, but at compile time. Is there a way to get such a thing done? What I need is some `static constexpr size_t` that at compile time will tell me what the position of `b` is within `mystruct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`offsetof` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof):

```
size_t constexpr b_offset = offsetof(mystruct, b);
```

Note, that you cannot use `offsetof` outside of functions in the same class definition because this class is incomplete yet.